# Include objTools in kernel debians (linux-headers and linux-image)

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, debian, ubuntu-18.04

We are compiling kernel and creating debians of linux kernel.
Recently, we found that it does not contain objTools source files in the debians.
Is there a way, we can include it in debians and will be available after installing debians?

We tried the following:
**Approach1:**
1. In config file, we enabled `CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION`
2. Ran `make-kpkg -j4 --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=-12 kernel_image kernel_headers`

**Approach2:**
1. In config file, we enabled `CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION`
2. Added *`(cd $srctree; find tools/objtool -type f -executable) >> "$objtree/debian/hdrsrcfiles" in scripts/package/builddeb`* file
3. Ran `make-kpkg -j4 --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=-12 kernel_image kernel_headers`

Both above created debian files but objTools folder had only Makefile inside linux-headers debian.

When I added `kernel_source` in make-kpkg command, it created debian but on installing it is showing `linux-source-12.tar.bz2`.

I want to get objTools folders along with all files on installing kernel debians i.e. linux-headers and linux-image debians such that when I install debians using command `dpkg -i linux-image*.deb linux-headers*.deb`, it should also install Tools source files.

Please help.

Comment: Do you need the source code itself, or are you after the compiled tool? `objtool` itself is available in the various `linux-kbuild` packages, *e.g.* `linux-kbuild-4.19`, in `/usr/lib/linux-kbuild-4.19/tools/objtool/objtool`.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the patch mentioned in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=833500;filename=kernel-package_add_objtool.patch;msg=10 and it worked.